# What happened? Why can't I dock the window on the side to switch the desktop?

Tags: macos, desktop, window-manager

In the past months, I can hold a app window on the left or right side of screen for some seconds to switch to nearby desktop. However, it started not to work these days. What is the reason?[image]

Comment: Have you updated your OS recently?

Comment: Is an open space available?

Comment: Yes, it's 13.2.1 now. @Thinkr

Comment: Yes, it is. Please look at the Gif above, there is an open desktop on the right. @Allan